# How to loop a df in panda to different sheets, so the output in one df is not overwrite by the next one

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, network-programming, netmiko

I'm trying to parse data for a lot of devices, and put it in order on a excel or csv.

This is the script:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from getpass import getpass
from netmiko.ssh_exception import NetMikoTimeoutException
from netmiko.ssh_exception import NetMikoAuthenticationException
from paramiko.ssh_exception import SSHException
import pandas as pd

IP_LIST=open('devices.txt')

for IP in IP_LIST:
    RTR = {
        'ip':IP,
        'username': 'jorales',
        'password': getpass(),
        'device_type': 'cisco_xr',
    }
    print ('\n #### Connecting to the Device ' + IP.strip() + ' ####\n')
    try:
        net_connect = ConnectHandler(**RTR)
    except NetMikoTimeoutException:
        print('Device not reachable')
        continue
    except NetMikoAuthenticationException:
        print ('Authentication Failure')
        continue
    except SSHException:
        print('Make sure SSH is enabled')
        continue
    data = []
    data.extend(net_connect.send_command('show ip int brief', use_textfsm=True))


    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(df)
    df.to_excel("Output1.xlsx", index=False)
```

The thing is that I have a bunch of IPs on "devices.txt" and I want to separate each one by sheets or print everyone in one but in order.

How could I do that, cause currently every output of the last device overwrite the first one.

Output:

```
 #### Connecting to the Device 10.192.33.115 ####

                    intf           ipaddr    status proto      vrf
0              Loopback0    10.192.33.115        Up    Up  default
1              Loopback1   190.56.112.237        Up    Up  default
2             Loopback10  216.230.136.196        Up    Up  default
3              PW-Ether1  216.230.137.177        Up    Up  default
4             PW-Ether11      10.87.54.89        Up    Up  default
5             PW-Ether12    10.31.109.217        Up    Up  default
6             PW-Ether28     10.31.73.137      Down  Down  default
7             PW-Ether39   10.174.181.157  Shutdown  Down  default
8             PW-Ether41   10.174.196.145      Down  Down  default
9   MgmtEth0/RSP0/CPU0/0       unassigned  Shutdown  Down  default
10  MgmtEth0/RSP0/CPU0/1       unassigned  Shutdown  Down  default
11        TenGigE0/0/2/0     10.192.41.74        Up    Up  default
12        TenGigE0/0/2/1     10.192.41.78        Up    Up  default
13        TenGigE0/0/2/2       unassigned  Shutdown  Down  default
14        TenGigE0/0/2/3       unassigned  Shutdown  Down  default

 #### Connecting to the Device 10.192.35.173 ####

                     intf         ipaddr    status proto      vrf
0               Loopback0  10.192.35.173        Up    Up  default
1  GigabitEthernet0/0/0/0  10.192.41.102        Up    Up  default
2     MgmtEth0/RP0/CPU0/0     unassigned  Shutdown  Down  default
```

What appears on the excel:

```
                     intf         ipaddr    status proto      vrf
0               Loopback0  10.192.35.173        Up    Up  default
1  GigabitEthernet0/0/0/0  10.192.41.102        Up    Up  default
2     MgmtEth0/RP0/CPU0/0     unassigned  Shutdown  Down  default
```

Answer (score 0):

df.to_excel(excel_writer="Output1.xlsx", index=False)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).